# Помогите пожалуйста как менять вторую картинку по клику?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function light(sw) {
        var pic;
        if (sw == 0) {
          pic = "icon/svet.png"
        } else {
          pic = "icon/svet1.png"
        }
        document.getElementById("myImage").src = pic;



      }
    </script>
    <img id="myImage" src="icon/svet.png" width="100" height="180">

    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="light(1)">Свет</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="light(0)"><strike>Свет</button>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="2">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function light(sw) {
        var pic;
        if (sw == 0) {
          pic = "icon/svet.png"
        } else {
          pic = "icon/svet1.png"
        }
        document.getElementById("myImage").src = pic;


      }
    </script>
    <img id="myImage" src="icon/svet.png" width="100" height="180">

    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="light(1)">Свет</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="light(0)"><strike> Свет</button>
    </p>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете один и тот же id для двух картинок, и из-за этого Вы не можете изменить вторую картинку: код берёт первый элемент с данным ID, невзирая на другой:

```html
<img id="myImage" src="icon/svet.png" width="100" height="180"> <!-- пикча №1 -->
...
<img id="myImage" src="icon/svet.png" width="100" height="180"> <!-- пикча №2 -->
```

Даже после изменения id на различные (и, соответственно, изменения id в функциях) встаёт другая проблема: теперь уже первая картинка не будет прогружаться, поскольку имя функции `light` одинаково для двух картинок => будет браться та функция, которая стоит в коде последней (т.е. для второй картинки). Поменяйте название второй функции на другое, и тогда все процессы будут выполняться независимо друг от друга.

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function light(sw) {
        var pic;
        if (sw == 0) {
          pic = "icon/svet.png"
        } else {
          pic = "icon/svet1.png"
        }
        document.getElementById("myImage").src = pic;
      }
    </script>
    <img id="myImage" src="icon/svet.png" width="100" height="180">
    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="light(1)">Свет</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="light(0)"><strike>Свет</button>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="2">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function light2(sw) {
        var pic;
        if (sw == 0) {
          pic = "icon/svet.png"
        } else {
          pic = "icon/svet1.png"
        }
        document.getElementById("myImage2").src = pic;
      }
    </script>
    <img id="myImage2" src="icon/svet.png" width="100" height="180">
    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="light2(1)">Свет</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="light2(0)"><strike> Свет</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста. Желательно закрыть в таком случае вопрос, отметив верный (на Ваш взгляд) вариант галочкой.